# React Native Firebase Firestore data fetching with empty spaces

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have created 3 documents in Firestore database, each document has different data.

but When I add different data on different document ids then I am getting blank spaces, and those spaces are generated automatically for other document ids which I already created previously.

Document 1 should be shown on First screen and document 2 should show on screen two. I mean each document's data should show on its own screen. please check the image link below-

[image]

[image]
[image]

```
First Screen



 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import {View, Button, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, Pressable, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
    import {firebase} from '../config';
    
    const Testing = ({ navigation }) =>{
      const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
      const todoRef = firebase.firestore().collection('testing');
    
    
      useEffect(() => {
          todoRef.onSnapshot(
              querySnapshot => {
                  const users = []
                  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                      const {    One, Two, Three
                
                      } = doc.data()
                      users.push({
                          id: doc.id,
                          One, Two, Three
                        
                      })
                  })
                  setUsers(users)
              }
          )
      }, [])
    return (
    
       <View style={{ flex:1,}}>
       <FlatList 
      style={{height: '100%'}}
      data={users}
      numColumns={1}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
     <Pressable >
    <View style={styles.viewOne}>
      <View>
      <Text style={[styles.card, styles.title]}>{item.One}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.text}>{item.Two}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item.Three}</Text>
    </View>
        </View>
         </Pressable>
    )} />
    </View>
    );}
    export default Testing;


*Second Screen*


import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {View, Button, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, Pressable, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import {firebase} from '../config';

const TestingDocs = ({ navigation }) =>{
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const todoRef = firebase.firestore().collection('testing');


  useEffect(() => {
      todoRef.onSnapshot(
          querySnapshot => {
              const users = []
              querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                  const {   DocsOne, DocsTwo, DocsThree, 
            
                  } = doc.data()
                  users.push({
                      id: doc.id,
                    DocsOne, DocsTwo, DocsThree, 
                    
                  })
              })
              setUsers(users)
          }
      )
  }, [])
return (

   <View style={{ flex:1,}}>
   <FlatList 
  style={{height: '100%'}}
  data={users}
  numColumns={1}
  renderItem={({item}) => (
 <Pressable >
<View style={styles.viewOne}>
  <View>
 <Text style={[styles.card, styles.title]}>{item.DocsOne}</Text>
<Text style={styles.text}>{item.DocsTwo}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.text}>{item.DocsThree}</Text>
</View>
    </View>
     </Pressable>
)} />
</View>
);}
export default TestingDocs;
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Firestore document ?

Comment: Thanks for your response Sir, I attached the screenshot here please check.

Comment: I created 3 document id in Firestore that's why in the image I am getting 3 row and if I create 10 document id then there would be 10 rows in the screen. suppose if I want to fetch data from document id number 5 then data fetch successfully but the problem is all those 10 empty rows will also appear in the screen. I don't want those empty rows I want only some particular document id data without those empty rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have seen this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73509125/15774176) on your another Post :

> It looks like you've incomplete or "optional" data in your backend. If
> you don't want to render empty fields you can conditionally render
> them.
>
> For the `users` data that is missing both properties you can filter
> the `data` prop.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>   <FlatList
>       data={users.filter(({ One, five }) => One || five)}
>       renderItem={({ item }) => (
>         <View style={{ .... }}>
>           {item.One && <Text>ID: {item.One}</Text>}
>           {item.five && <Text>Name: {item.five}</Text>}
>         </View>
>       )}
>     />
> ```

You can also refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63155575/15774176):

> Its as a result of performance issues with the FlatList component but
> you can add the following props to your FlatList Component, it would
> help solve the problem. **They are:**
> **i.** removeClippedSubviews.
> Set this to true, it comes with a default of false.
> **ii.** windowSize. Set this to a number like say 30
> **iii.** maxToRenderPerBatch. This controls the number of items rendered per batch, which is the next chunk of items rendered on every
> scroll.
>
> ```
> <FlatList
>             data={this.state.contacts}
>             removeClippedSubviews={true}
>             maxToRenderPerBatch={60}
>             windowSize={30}
>             ListHeaderComponent={headerComponent}
>             contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 10 }}
>             renderItem={({ item }) => (
>               <View>
>                 {item}
>               </View>
>             )}
>             numColumns={1}
>             keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
>           />
> ```

For more information, you can refer to the [blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-react-hooks-firebase-firestore/) which explains how to use react hooks with firebase firestore.