# React Native Firebase Firestore data not fetching properly

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I want to fetch data only which data I call in my app, it's working very well but why I am getting all those unnecessary parts, how to remove that, thanks for your support. please check the database image and display output image how it's displaying. I don't want those parts where I marked red lines, because I have not call them in my code. Is it FlatList issue or Firebase issue?  [image] [image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import {firebase} from '../config';

const Testing = ({ navigation }) =>{
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Set loading to true on component mount
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firebase.firestore()
      .collection('testing')
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const users = [];
  
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
          users.push({
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
            key: documentSnapshot.id,
          });
        });
  
        setUsers(users);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  
    // Unsubscribe from events when no longer in use
    return () => subscriber();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <ActivityIndicator />;
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={users}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={{ height: 50, flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>ID: {item.One}</Text>
          <Text>Name: {item.five}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    />
  );}   
export default Testing;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've incomplete or "optional" data in your backend. If you don't want to render empty fields you can conditionally render them.

For the `users` data that is missing both properties you can filter the `data` prop.

Example:

```
<FlatList
  data={users.filter(({ One, five }) => One || five)}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View style={{ .... }}>
      {item.One && <Text>ID: {item.One}</Text>}
      {item.five && <Text>Name: {item.five}</Text>}
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

Comment: Yes Sir Drew, I have optional data in backend and I don't want to render them with empty field.
Thank you so much for your great support it's working now and hope I will not get any issues with this code because I have many incomplete and optional data available in database and I don't want to remove them from database.