# How to filter Firebase Firestore Array data in React native app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-flatlist

I want to fetch only values of '1' and '3' from the Arraytesting(array part). Please check the Image so that you will understand my question. Can I solve this by coding inside Flatlist part or do I need to change the Firestore data fetching method?

And if I fetch data from Array there should not be an empty field for the remaining value of 0, 2. Yesterday I posted a question that question was similar to this question but this time I am trying to fetch only array data. @DrewReese supported me on that problem. Please check my previous question link- [React Native Firebase Firestore data not fetching properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73509103/react-native-firebase-firestore-data-not-fetching-properly)

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import {firebase} from '../config';

const Testing = ({ navigation }) =>{
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Set loading to true on component mount
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firebase.firestore()
      .collection('testing')
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const users = [];
  
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
          users.push({
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
            key: documentSnapshot.id,
          });
        });
  
        setUsers(users);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  
    // Unsubscribe from events when no longer in use
    return () => subscriber();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <ActivityIndicator />;
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={users}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={{ height: 50, flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>ID: {item.One}</Text>
          <Text>Name: {item.five}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    />
  );}   
export default Testing;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try something like this :
filtering out for index 1 and index 3

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, View, Text } from 'react-native';
    import {firebase} from '../config';
    
    const Testing = ({ navigation }) =>{
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Set loading to true on component mount
      const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
      const [filteredusers, setFiltered] = useState([])
      useEffect(() => {
        const subscriber = firebase.firestore()
          .collection('testing')
          .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
            const users = [];
      
            querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
              users.push({
                ...documentSnapshot.data(),
                key: documentSnapshot.id,
              });
            });
      
            setUsers(users);
            //setting here
            const newFiltered = users?.filter((data,index) => (index === 1 || index ===3) );
            setFiltered(newFiltered)
            setLoading(false);
          });
      
        // Unsubscribe from events when no longer in use
        return () => subscriber();
      }, []);
    
      if (loading) {
        return <ActivityIndicator />;
      }
    
      return (
        <FlatList
          data={filteredusers} // users is now filtered
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={{ height: 50, flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              <Text>ID: {item?.id}</Text>
              <Text>Name: {item?.name}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      );}   
    export default Testing;
```

Comment: Please check the image link data is not fetched yet- https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QPfK.png

Comment: @RahulAadam can you share the console.log for users ?? what is the response? ill change acc

Comment: Sir, I have not get any error in the console, please check the image link  https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOxaG.png  .I think everything is fine we just need to work on this lines -   <Text>ID: {item?.id}</Text>
              <Text>Name: {item?.name}</Text> or maybe in flatlist

Comment: yes, thats what, im @RahulAadam im asking just console log what does a user object contain

Does it even contain id and name as its properties

Comment: can you share me what does ```users``` array look like